# pass pointer to java with NDK on Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

i want to use `memset` in a Android program.
i try NDK to code in C then use library in my JAVA Android's program.

input of `memset` is `*ptr`.i want to send a Memory Address (like `0x8134`) to program and then use `memset` to change it.how could i send this to my program?

Answer (score 1):

First, as you know, Java does not have the concept of pointers and thus cannot really allocate/use a memory area using pointers(on which memset needs to be used).

That said, it is possible to use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` to get a *direct* byte buffer whose address can be used on the native side of JNI to do direct memory operations. Further, you can directly allocate memory in the native code and pass it back to the Java code as a ByteBuffer. This is the closest you can get to C/C++ type memory access/manipulation.

More details:

 http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/10/02/javanio.html?page=2 

 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html